# Bad file descriptor pipes Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe

The following code always throw me an errors like `read file child: Bad file descriptor` or `read file child: No error`.

Parent create child process, that read data from anonymous parent's pipe. Error occurs while getting `HANDLE` from std.

parent.cpp:

```
sinfo.hStdInput = pipe_read;
/****some code********/
if(!CreateProcess(0, szCmdline, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &sinfo, &pinfo))
{
    perror("create process");
    exit(1);
}
/****some code********/

if(!WriteFile(pipe_write, &to_process, sizeof(int)*20, &bytes, 0))
{
    perror("write file parent");
    exit(1);
}

vector<int> sorted;
if(!ReadFile(pipe_read1, &sorted, sizeof(int)*20, 0, 0))
{
    perror("read file parent");
    exit(1);
}
```

child.cpp:

```
/****some code********/

HANDLE pipe_read = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

/****some code********/

if(!ReadFile(pipe_read, &to_process, sizeof(int)*20, &bytes, 0))
{
    perror("read file child");
    exit(1);
}
/****some code********/
```

What problems with my code? Addresses of received (in child) and forwarded (in parent) are equals.

Comment: You don't check if the `HANDLE` is valid. Also, you have no code to handle normal close of the pipe.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz GetHandleInformation return 0. And what the reason, that can make `HANDLE` invalid? I'm just writing to it from parent process

Comment: Use the boilerplate SDK sample code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx